# CQ 5.5 i18n and accept-lanugage header

Tags: java, servlets, internationalization, adobe, aem

I try to use i18n localization but I have stuck.

If I use:

```
I18n i18n = new I18n(slingRequest);
i18n.get("myMessage");
```

I always get the english message for key: myMessage.

In accept-language header I can see these values: de,en;q=0.5

but:

- request.getLocale() returns: en
- request.getLocales() returns: en

If I use code below everything is good:

```
Locale myLocale = new Locale("de");    
ResourceBundle resourceBundle = slingRequest.getResourceBundle(myLocale);   
I18n i18n = new I18n(resourceBundle);
```

Why don't cq read "accept-language" request headers?

ps: I use standalone cq jar...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CQ/Sling (as of 5.6) does **not** read the Accept-Language header for the locale you get via `slingRequest.getLocale()` (or `slingRequest.getResourceBundle(null)` which implicitly uses that locale), instead it uses the user's language setting (`~/preferences/@language` in the JCR) or a configurable default (1).

The reasoning is that a fixed setting is much stabler, also when using different browsers across devices, than guessing the language header.

But it's **extensible**: you can hook in a custom [org.apache.sling.i18n.RequestLocaleResolver](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/org/apache/sling/i18n/RequestLocaleResolver.html) service (with a higher service rank), which is the service that provides the value for `slingRequest.getLocale()` (2). This could also take the accept language into account; it gets access to the underlying servlet request object, which should give you the Accept-Language header value in `getLocale()` and `getLocales()` (at least the built-in servlet engine in CQ does that since 5.4).

(1) Configure default locale on this service: `http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.JcrResourceBundleProvider`

(2) Sling's `I18nFilter` which you probably have seen in stack traces already does all the magic and wraps the request to provide the `slingRequest.getLocale()` and `slingRequest.getResourceBundle()` implementations using the `RequestLocaleResolver` and `ResourceBundleProvider` services

Answer (score 0):

Is the first code example copy pasted? If the sample is pasted from your code, then a typo in your key may be the issue because the language key in your example is "myMesage" and not "myMessage" as indicated later in your post.

Comment: Sorry I changed the code when I copied here (only the message key). So  it is a typo only here... I've fixed it now in the question. But the problem remains. I cannot figure out why CQ doesn't use accept-language header...

Comment: I was able to reproduce the same behaviour, which is not the expected one but explainable as the SlingHttpServletRequests getLocale() method resolves the primary Locale either by evaluating the Accept-Language request header or the server's default locale, depending on the methods underlying Servlet Container implementation.
I guess it does not evaluate the Accept-Header but the servers default locale which is likely a bug as the CQ API describes a different behaviour for the DefaultLocaleResolver.
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/org/apache/sling/i18n/DefaultLocaleResolver.html